# Graphical Interpretation of f''(x)>0

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

what is the graphical interpretation of the fact that a f''(x) >0 for a range of values of x? I am confused if it would give a number of minimas or something else. Really confused :|

Answer (score 2):

The second derivative determines whether a function is [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) (for $f''>0$) or [concave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function) (for $f''<0$). (And $f''=0$ may be the [inflection point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point), if changes sign there.)